# Gcc: making UTF-8 the execution character set

Tags: c++, gcc, utf-8, character-encoding

I wrote this test program in a Latin-1 encoded file...

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char str[] = "ÅÄÖ";

int main() {
  cout << sizeof(str) << ' ' << strlen(str) << ' '
    << sizeof("Åäö") << ' ' << strlen("åäö") << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

...and compiled it with `g++ -fexec-charset=UTF-8 -pedantic -Wall` on OpenBSD 5.3. I was expecting to see the size of the strings being 6 chars + 1 NUL char, but I get the output `4 3 4 3`?

I tried changing my system locale from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 with `export LC_CTYPE=sv_SE.UTF-8`, but that didn't help. (Accordning to the gcc manual, that only changes the *input* character set, but hey, it was worth a try.)

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set `-finput-charset` as well?

Comment: @KerrekSB When I do, I get this error message: `cc1plus: error: no iconv implementation, cannot convert from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8`. The same thing happens when I use `L1` or `LATIN1`, even though these are listed with `iconv -l`.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? If you just want to output a string in UTF-8, then you could always convert it from the original Latin-1/

Comment: "error: no iconv implementation" means there was no libiconv when GCC was built. If GCC was compiled without iconv support, it won't use iconv, even if at runtime it turns out iconv is present.

Comment: Works for me with `-finput-charset=Latin1 -fexec-charset=UTF-8`.